# Obtaining an JSON Token using Authentication in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

Hi fairly new to iOS just trying to connect the app to an API and get my token using Authentication. I have tried a lot of different options and just can't seem to get my head around it. All i'm trying to do is obtain my token. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong? The API documentation is here: https://simplybook.me/en/api/developer-api

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://user-api.simplybook.me/login/"];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"myloginname" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Company-Login"];
[request setValue:@"mytokenhere" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Token"];

NSURLSessionDataTask *downloadTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {

        id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
        NSArray * resultDict =[json objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSLog(@"%@", resultDict);

    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }
}];

[downloadTask resume];
```

Comment: Have you tried using `https` instead of `http` in the api url? Also, is the `downloadTask` executed or do you receive any error upon firing the request?

Comment: Using https now still the same issue. No error from downloadTask

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declaring `NSURLSession` like this:

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
```

Try this instead:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://user-api.simplybook.me/login/"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                       timeoutInterval:60.0];
```

And also, make sure you've declared the `NSURLSessionDelegate` protocol in your header file.

Comment: I've tried this with no luck. The session was working fine. It is just using the headers to try and get my access token that I am stuck on.

Comment: @user7322261 Ok, sorry I thought It could've been a problem related to `sharedSession`; One last thing you can try, switch to `addValue` instead of `setValue` for the custom headers

Comment: Still no good thanks though! Do you know what my HTTP header fields should be from the API documentation?

Comment: @user7322261 I took a quick look at the docs and the 2 headers you've set seems to be correct. You can also try adding this one to the request:
`[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];`

Comment: Ah i've just noticed above where I wrote the mytokenhere line that is actually the API Key. And i'm just trying to get the token I don't actually have it yet. On the documentation they use var token = loginClient.getToken(YOUR_COMPANY_LOGIN, YOUR_API_KEY);

Answer (score 0):

I will give you sample code for getting token but this is regarding to the access and refresh token.You can understand it very clearly now.

ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (IBAction)actionLogin:(id)sender {
     [self loginForGettingAccessandRefreshToken];
}

-(void)loginForGettingAccessandRefreshToken
{
  @try {

         NSString *strUserName = [textUsername.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
         NSString *strPassword = [textPassword.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

         NSString *strParameters = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"client_id=roclient&client_secret=secret&grant_type=password&username=%@&password=%@&scope=dataEventRecords offline_access", strUserName, strPassword];

        id param = strParameters;
        NSLog(@"The param is - %@",param);

       [GlobalShareClass postLoginDataToServer:BASEURL_LOGIN passParameters:param success:^(id res)
       {
           if([res isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){

            NSDictionary *dictRes = [res copy];
            NSString *strErrDesc = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dictRes objectForKey:@"error_description"]];

            if([[dictRes allKeys] containsObject:@"error_description"]){
             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                  //Dispaly UI
             });
         }
         else{
              NSString *strAccessToken = [dictRes objectForKey:@"access_token"];
             NSString *strRefreshToken = [dictRes objectForKey:@"refresh_token"];
             NSString *strTokenType = [dictRes objectForKey:@"token_type"];
             NSString *sstrExpiresIn = [dictRes objectForKey:@"expires_in"];

             [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:globalShare.strRefreshToken forKey:@"refresh_token"];
             [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:globalShare.strAccessToken forKey:@"access_token"];
             [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

             NSDictionary *responseDict = [GlobalShareClass getDataFromToken:globalShare.strAccessToken];


             NSString *strFetchedSub = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"loginIdSub"];


             globalShare.loginId = [responseDict objectForKey:@"sub"];

        }
      }
      else{
         NSLog(@"The res starts with array");
      }


 } failure:^(NSError *error) {
     // error handling here ...
     NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //Showing Error
     });
 } passViewController:self];
}
@catch(NSException *exception){
    NSLog(@"%@",[exception description]);
}
@finally{

}
}
}
```

GlobalShareClass.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface GlobalShareClass : NSObject{
   NSMutableArray  *arr;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray  *arr;
+ (GlobalShareClass *)sharedInstance;
+ (void)postLoginDataToServer:(NSString *)url passParameters:(id)parameter success:(void (^)(id res))successPost failure:(void(^)(NSError* error))failurePost passViewController:(UIViewController *)vc;
+ (NSDictionary *)getDataFromToken:(NSString *)strToken;
+ (NSDictionary *)urlBase64Decode:(NSString *)strToParse;

@end
```

GlobalShareClass.m

```
#import "GlobalShareClass.h"

@implementation GlobalShareClass
@synthesize arr;

+ (GlobalShareClass *)sharedInstance {
   static GlobalShareClass* _shareInstane = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _shareInstane = [[GlobalShareClass alloc] init];
        //Incase array of initialization
        _shareInstane.arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    });

    return _shareInstane;
}


 + (void)postLoginDataToServer:(NSString *)url passParameters:(id)parameter success:(void (^)(id res))successPost failure:(void(^)(NSError* error))failurePost passViewController:(UIViewController *)vc{
    GlobalShareClass *globalShare = [GlobalShareClass sharedInstance];
    __block id jsonResp;
    NSData *data = [parameter dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
    NSURLSessionUploadTask *dataTask = [session uploadTaskWithRequest: request
                                                             fromData:data completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                                 if(data == nil && error){
                                                                     NSLog(@"uploadTaskWithRequest error: %@", error);


                                                                     failurePost(error);
                                                                 }
                                                                 else{
                                                                     jsonResp = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

                                                                     NSString *strStatusCode = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)[((NSHTTPURLResponse *)response) statusCode]];
                                                                     if([strStatusCode isEqualToString:@"400"]){

                                                                         successPost(jsonResp);
                                                                     }
                                                                     NSString *strStatusCodeResponse = [self strGetStatusResponseCode:strStatusCode];
                                                                     if([strStatusCodeResponse length] > 0){
                                                                         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                                     // Showing error                                                                            

                                                                         });
                                                                         }else{
                                                                         jsonResp = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
                                                                         if([jsonResp objectForKey:@"error"] || jsonResp == nil){
                                                                             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                                                                       [self showAlertController:@"Error" :[jsonResp objectForKey:@"error_description"] passViewController:vc];
                                                                             });
                                                                         }
                                                                         else
                                                                             successPost(jsonResp);
                                                                     }
                                                                 }
                                                             }];
    [dataTask resume];
}


+ (NSDictionary *)getDataFromToken:(NSString *)strToken {
    NSDictionary *data;
    NSString *encoded = [strToken componentsSeparatedByString:@"."][1];
    data = [GlobalShareClass urlBase64Decode:encoded];
    return data;
}



 + (NSDictionary *)urlBase64Decode:(NSString *)strToParse {
    @try {
        NSDictionary *returnDict;
        NSString *output = [strToParse stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@"+"];
        output = [output stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"_" withString:@"/"];

        switch (output.length % 4) {
            case 0:
            case 1:
                break;
            case 2:
                output = [output stringByAppendingString:@"=="];
                break;
            case 3:
                output = [output stringByAppendingString:@"="];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:output options:0];
        NSString *decodedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decodedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@", decodedString);

        NSData *data = [decodedString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        returnDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

        return returnDict;
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [exception description]);
    }
}

@end
```